# Can we Increment the global variable name inside a for loop like a variable when using Postman

Tags: javascript, postman-testcase

I am trying to parse the response data and getting the values for the "id". Since I am expecting multiple values for the same response I am putting it into an array. Inside a for loop I increment the array with the index set to i. Each of these values i need to pass it to a global variable like var_id0, var_id1... var_idn.

Can the numeric against the global name "var_id" be incremented inside the for loop?

I looked up multiple examples but none are showing me if such a thing can be done when setting the global variable.

```
var index_id= [];
var jsonData = JSON.parse(responseBody);
for (var i = 0; i < jsonData.list.length; i++) {  
    var counter = jsonData.list[i];
    index_id[i] = counter.id;
    pm.globals.set("var_id"[i], index_id[i]) <<-- How can this be achieved.
    //pm.globals.set("variable name", "variable value") --> Actual syntax.
}
```

My expectation is that till the end of the for loop is reached, with each loop the global variable name, will be incremented by 1 and the corresponding value will be set.
For eg:

var_id1 = "700"
var_id2 = "800"...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`"var_id"[i]` means *look up the ith index in `"var_id"`*, and for strings that will evaluate to the character at position i, so `"var_id"[0]` would be `"v"`. Instead, you want to build up strings by *appending* `i` to `"var_id"`, that can be done with `+`.

Comment: Hi Jonas Wilms, that worked like a charm. Thank you. By adding a +, as you mentioned, it helps add a numeric against the global variable name. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
pm.globals.set("var_id"[i], index_id[i])
```

To

```
pm.globals.set(`var_id${i}`, index_id[i])
```

Comment: Hi Christopher Bradley, The problem with the above is that globals.set takes everything inside the quotes as the variable name and does not go about appending the values as desired.

Comment: Ah I see, do you have a sample of the response. I know you marked one as the answer but maybe theirs a more efficient way if i had a example of the response. Cheers!

Comment: This is what i caught in the global setting for the Postman:                  VARIABLE
INITIAL VALUE
CURRENT VALUE
var_id${[i]}
747
747

Comment: Ahh, i messed up on my end, check my edited answer without the brackets.

Comment: var_id${i}
732
732

Answer (score 1):

Why do you need all this global variables? Define one global array and push your values into it. Then access them by index. Almost the same syntax as you wanted.

Answer (score -3):

You can use `eval` function.

```
var index_id= [];
var jsonData = JSON.parse(responseBody);
for (var i = 0; i < jsonData.list.length; i++) {  
    var counter = jsonData.list[i];
    index_id[i] = counter.id;
    eval("var_id"+i+"="+index_id[i]);
    //pm.globals.set("var_id"[i], index_id[i]) <<-- How can this be achieved.
    //pm.globals.set("variable name", "variable value") --> Actual syntax.
}
```

Comment: thanks for a down vote without explanation. eval is sometimes not evil, accept it. :)

Comment: It's completely unesseccary here though, and you still have `"var_id"[i]`.

Comment: @Paulpro Do you mean the line after the line with eval? Which part is unnecessary?